# can I use other distributed cache in place of jboss cache for session replication in jboss

Tags: caching, jboss, cluster-computing, high-availability, terracotta

I am using jboss-cache for session replication in jboss 4.0.4. How do I use a different distributed cache(Terracotta or any other) in place of jboss cache?

Comment: Why?  What would they do that JBossCache wouldn't?

Comment: Its not about JBoss Cache can do it or not. When we have bought a caching solution we would want that to be used rather than add maintenance overhead by using different caching solutions in different places.

Comment: That;'s useful information ion itself.  If you have a specific solution in mind, then say so in the question. As it is, the question is vague and hard to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to repackage jars and configuration in your jboss server, but Tomcat has its own [clustering and session replication support](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/cluster-howto.html). Not that I recommend this approach. Any specific reason you don't want to use the built in session replication ? You may also find improvements in clustering and session replication in later versions of JBoss 4.x.

Here is documentation for [Terracotta For Web Sessions](http://www.terracotta.org/web-sessions/). If you disable clustering in your JBoss server and implement this, you should be good to go.

Comment: we have bought a caching solution that we want to use rather than add maintenance overhead by using different caching solutions in different places